# Issue with VS Test Task Version 2.229.0 - Failing to collect coverage

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, vstest

My VS Test task failing to collect coverage after azure devops task started picking up the version of VSTest@2 - 2.229.0. Pipeline was working fine earlier till version 2.228.0.

Blame: Attaching crash dump utility to process testhost.net48 (1548).
Data collection : Unable to find a datacollector with friendly name 'Code Coverage'.
Data collection : Could not find data collector 'Code Coverage'

It was working till version 2.228.0 of VsTest.

Can anyone give suggestion on this issue, is this some bug in the latest vstest version ?
No code update or changes made in our source code, Agent is using the default visual studio versions available for build and test.

Comment: Tested from my side using VSTest@2 - 2.229.0, code coverage is published successfully. 1. Are you using a MS-hosted agent or self-hosted agent? If it's a self-hosted agent, please try to use a MS-hosted agent and check what's the result. 2. In which task log did you see the message "Could not find data collector 'Code Coverage'"? It's VSTest? 3. Ensure that you have enabled code coverage `codeCoverageEnabled: true`. 4. Please try to use VSTest@3 and check if it works. 5. If it's convenient, would you please share your yaml file?

Comment: We are using self hosted agent. Coverage is enabled to true, Pipeline was successful  
with Visual Studio build Version : 1.229.0, Visual Studio Test Task Version : 2.228.0.
But pipeline started failing with: Visual Studio build Version : 1.231.0, Visual Studio Test Task Version : 2.229.0.
Tests are succeeding and generating report but coverage report generation is failing.
Data collection : Unable to find a datacollector with friendly name ‘Code Coverage’.
Data collection : Could not find data collector ‘Code Coverage’

Comment: and one more question @ZiyangLiu-MSFT I copuldn't find the VSTest@3 in official website. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vstest-v2?view=azure-pipelines

Comment: I don't find the official doc about VSTest@3, but it can be used in the pipeline. The current version is 3.225.0. To narrow down the issue. 1. Please run your test using VSTest@2 on a Microsoft-hosted agent. If code coverage report is generated successfully, the issue may be related to your local environment. 2. Please use VSTest@3 to run your test when using your self-hosted agent. If it works, the issue may be related to VSTest 2.229.0.